# numpy array traversal Error: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, numpy

numpy with shape (5,1)
with the following elements:

```
[[1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]]
```

how do you go about traversing through and printing each element?
as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Attempt

```
for row in range(N):
    for col in range(D):
        print(input_array[row][col])
```

Error

```
Error: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `N, D` values must be wrong. Either do

```
N, D = input_array.shape
```

and continue with your code, or directly

```
for row in input_array:
    for token in row:
        print(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the `N` value is wrong. It should be `[0]`.

Calculating with [numpy.ndarray.shape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape) function should return correct value of rows and columns.